# JS Regex last two digits matches the first two digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex, so please bare with my stupid question.

I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of hours now, and i still can't get i to work, as i want to.

What i need is, i have 4 number, and i need the last 2 numbers, to be the same as the first 2.
Like this would be a match:

```
1212  
1313  
1414
```

This in the other hand, should not be a match:

```
1513
1314
1236
```

I can't seem to get it to work, and i'm clueless on how to actually do it.
This is what i've got so far:

```
/^(?:(\d{2}))+$/g
```

Can i get some help, moving on? or a finger point in the right direction, on how to do it, or where to look it up, so i can find the answer my self.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(\d{2})\1$/
```

for 4 digit strings. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP3eA8/1).

```js
var good_strs = ["1212", "1313", "1414"];
var bad_strs = ["1513", "1314", "1236"];
var res_good = good_strs.map(x => /^(\d{2})\1$/.test(x));
document.body.innerHTML = "Good string test:<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res_good, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
var res_bad = bad_strs.map(x => /^(\d{2})\1$/.test(x));
document.body.innerHTML += "Bad string test:<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res_bad, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

If there can be any characters in between, just insert `[\s\S]*` in between:

```
/^(\d{2})[\s\S]*\1$/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP3eA8/3) (lazy matching used for demo only).

Comment: Thank you so much! i though i already tried that, but there you go, worked! Can you tell me why '\1' did the job, and what it does? if that's not to much to ask for.

Comment: That is a backreference to a  text that is already matched and *captured* with a pair of unescaped parentheses inside the regex pattern. See [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) for more details.

Comment: Ahh i see. Thank you for the explanation, and the link.